# Accessing global constants that can change

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

In php I can for example create a .inf file containing some constants defined and include it into the code, then if someone change the constantg inside it, it will be used updated.

Whats the similar approach to .net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that would be the `appSettings` in the web.config file:

```
<system.web>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="somekey" value="somevalue" />
    </appSettings>
</system.web>
```

Access it using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`:

```
string setting = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["somekey"];
```

(Note that you need to add a reference to `System.Configuration.dll` for this to work.)